# Wordpress testimonial slider and it's link with footer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, fullscreen

I am creating a [Wordpress website](http://solehealth.co.uk/) for one client.

On the home page, I added testimonials, when testimonials slider works, footer below also re-sized (up and down). I want to know how can I fix this thing?
I don't want the footer to move when client slider moves.

Comment: Is it a custom theme?

Comment: no. I selected the theme, and customized it.

Comment: Ah ok. Make sure your html tags are closed properly. You should put in some code to get a better understanding

Comment: it's wordpress website, so that mean I din't touch it's HTML, I just customized it.

Comment: Check if you closed the HTML tags and also make sure the CSS of the testimonial slider  isn't overriding the footer. If the footer works on other pages it's most likely the html tags aren't closed

Comment: The HTML is the content. Like I said it's hard to get a understanding with no code, images, etc..

Comment: its okay I guess I am not able to make you guys understand. Please have a look at the link, and http://solehealth.co.uk/ and try to inspect.

Comment: If it's this URL http://solehealth.co.uk/testimonial/testimonial-1/ it's working for me

Comment: @Tarson sir What I meant to say was, when slides are changed, footer also moves up and down. I want the footer remain fixed.

Comment: Ooooh, really? It's kind of a design feature that gives it move of a interactive look. It's very nice actually. But if you want the sized fixed I will give you a fix when I get near a Computer.

Comment: @Tarson sir I really want a fix, thank you so much. yes its nice feature,  but it is user requirements. So it also means I don't need to remove my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should calc the min-height dynamically via jQuery

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(window).resize(function () {

        var minHeight = -1;
        $('.home-testimonial .slides > li').each(function() {
          minHeight = minHeight > $(this).height() ? minHeight : $(this).height();
        });
        minHeight+=300;
        $('.home-testimonial').css('min-height', minHeight+'px');

        });
   });
```

this will see the longest testimonial you have and put the main height of the container based to it so it will work if you have very long testimonial or on mobile

Comment: if it work for you please dont forget to make the Q as solved and select the right answer so other people will benefit from it

Comment: how to mark question solved? and confirm I have selected the right answer?

Comment: as you did by add the right mark this help other visitor to know that this Q is solved and this is the accepted answer you use the vote up as well to bring the answer you like to top ... you can check the tour page ... http://stackoverflow.com/tour ...

Comment: please visit the link, it is still happening on mobile size window. is there any solution for that? link: http://solehealth.co.uk/

Comment: the code work 1 time when page load try to resize the window to mobile size and reload you will see it works fin ... we can add some code to resize ever time the window size change ... but it will be process we dont need ...

Comment: yes I reloaded the page on mobile size window, still happening, do I need to add anything like media query?

Comment: you are useing this css .home-testimonial {
    min-height: 625px !important;
} remove it .... and I change the code now it will re calculate on resize

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a WordPress question, is more of a CSS question.

As the testimonials transition, the content below (in this case the footer) is following it up / down.

In order to prevent this, you need to add some CSS that will add a `min-height` to the testimonial container.

The following CSS will work **with the length of testimonials you have now**.  If your testimonials get longer, then the number will have to be increased:

```
.home-testimonial {
    min-height: 625px;
}
```

You can add this to your theme's stylesheet, or any custom styles areas they allow you to set up.

Comment: btw this is first answer come to my mind so +up ... but the problem here is 1 testimonial is really long it will more the footer up and down ... plus on mobile devices it will keep going up and down because the testominals is really long ...